# What happens to modules required in exported modules Node?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I've been trying to modularize my server and web apps. i've read about exports and module.exports in Node here and here.

http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

http://liangzan.net/blog/blog/2012/06/04/how-to-use-exports-in-nodejs/

I get how it makes the functions available to other files / scripts, but what happens to the modules required within the exported file? If I require websockets in some file, export it and require it within another file, does the other file inherit the websockets from the exported file? Is it similar to a header file in C and just pastes that module into your file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `require()` a module in node, it gets executed inside a closure and the value exported by the module is cached. So any additional `require()`s for the same module (located at the same absolute path) will always get the same object/value/whatever.

So in your websockets example, the `require('websockets')` that you do in your module is not automagically available to anyone requiring your module. Everything in a module is done within a separate, local scope (you can read/write the global scope accessible by all modules, but you *really* should *not* do that). This is why you need to explicitly export values for them to be seen by outsiders.